# Adjust name of file being read at end of loop without breaking loop

Tags: c#, date, increment

There are 2 reports that are produced at the end of each day. I would like to be able to perform analysis on them at the end of each month.

Inside each file is a thousand lines or so of long ASCII strings. This has been successfully coded, but only to extract and perform analysis on one file at a time.

I'll try and put in the relevant structure of the code below.. I hope this is enough to get an idea of what needs to be done. If not, I am happy to post the entire thing.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("YYYYMMDD----1234D.dat"))
{
while loop //this goes through all the lines in the file. 
{if //if meets certain criteria then store into a list, otherwise ignore

}
foreach // this part does the analysis of all the values in the list, totals, etc
```

.

The first report is in the above format, and the other has a different number in place of 1234D (for arguments sake,5678D, so: yyyymmdd----5678D). Both these numbers are constant throughout.

I'd like to be able to have all the data stored into my list from every file, and then perform the analysis on the entire month, rather than have a daily breakdown, so it would loop through each file, when it gets to the end of the file, increment the name by a day, loop through that etc. (or find all files with a month of X - whichever is better). This would populate the list, and then the foreach would perform its analysis and output. It is expected that I will put all the required files into the same folder as the one currently used by the program.

CURRENT CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;

class Program 
{
    public class EntryLine
    {
        public int I { get; set; }
        public string LineStart { get; set; }
        public string Letters { get; set; }
        public int TVolume { get; set; }
        public long TPrice { get; set; }
        public double MVolume { get; set; }
        public string Currency { get; set; }
        public string DateTime {get; set; }

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<EntryLine> myList = new List<EntryLine>();
        int i = 1;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("20121203----1234D.dat"))
        {
            string line;
            var locations = new Dictionary<string, int[]>() {
            {"210", new [] {405, 4, 128, 12, 141, 12, 247, 15, 121, 3}}, 
            {"310", new [] {321, 4, 112, 12, 125, 12, 230, 15, 105, 3}}, 
            {"410", new [] {477, 4, 112, 12, 125, 12, 360, 15, 105, 3}} 
        };

            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var lineStart = line.Substring(0, 3);

                if (lineStart == "210" || lineStart == "310" || lineStart == "410")
                {
                    var currentLocations = locations[lineStart];
                    var letters = line.Substring(currentLocations[0], currentLocations[1]);

                    var tvolume =
                        int.Parse(line.Substring(currentLocations[2], currentLocations[3])) +
                        int.Parse(line.Substring(currentLocations[4], currentLocations[5]));

                    var tprice = long.Parse(line.Substring(currentLocations[6], currentLocations[7]));
                    var mvolume = tprice * tvolume * 0.01 * 0.0000001;
                    var currency = line.Substring(currentLocations[8], currentLocations[9]);

                    myList.Add(new EntryLine()
                    {
                        I = i,
                        LineStart = lineStart,
                        Letters = letters,
                        TVolume = tvolume,
                        TPrice = tprice,
                        MVolume = mvolume,
                        Currency = currency
                    });
                    i = i + 1;
                }
            }

            var x = myList.GroupBy(g => new { g.Letters, g.Currency })
                .Select(a => new { a.Key.Letters, a.Key.Currency, TSum = a.Sum(s => s.TVolume), MSum = a.Sum(s => s.MVolume) });

            foreach (var item in x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} currency: {1} tvolume: {2} mVolume: {3}", item.Letters, item.Currency, item.TSum, item.MSum);
            }
        } Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. Here's one option: first, break the procedure down into a couple functions for easier code maintenance. Then use one function to loop through all files and build a list of information, and another to analyze that information.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ReportAnalysis {
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        //lets run the analysis for Nov, 2012

        //First, read in all report files, and store relevant lines
        var reportInfo = ReportAnalyzer.ReadFiles(2012, 11);

        //Now analyze all files at once
        ReportAnalyzer.RunAnalysis(reportInfo);
    }
}
class ReportAnalyzer {
    struct ReportFile {
        public string Path;
        public DateTime Date;
        public List<string> Lines;
    }

    public static IList<ReportFile> ReadFiles(int year, int month) {
        //Put names of files here.
        string[] fileNames = new string[] { "{0:YYYYMMDD}----1234D.dat", "{0:YYYYMMDD}----5678D.dat" };

        DateTime dateStart = new DateTime(year, month, 1); //start of month
        DateTime dateEnd = dateStart.AddMonths(1); //start of NEXT month (i.e. 1 day past end of this month)

        var reportList = new List<ReportFile>();

        DateTime date = dateStart;
        while (date < dateEnd) {  //we don't actually get to dateEnd, just the day before it.
            foreach (var fileTemplate in fileNames) {
                //insert the date in YYYYMMDD format
                var file = string.Format(fileTemplate, date);
                if (File.Exists(file)) {
                    var report = new ReportFile() {
                        Date = date,
                        Path = file,
                        Lines = GetReportLines(file)
                    };
                    reportList.Add(report);
                }
            }
            //now jump to next day
            date = date.AddDays(1);
        }
        return reportList;
    }

    private static List<string> GetReportLines(string file) {
        var lines = new List<string>();
        try {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file)) {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
                    var line = reader.ReadLine();
                    if (true /* insert criteria */)
                        lines.Add(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //log the error however you see fit
            lines.Add(string.Format("ERROR Could not open report file {0}: {1}", file, ex.Message));
        }
        return lines;
    }

    public static void RunAnalysis(IList<ReportFile> reports) {
        foreach (var r in reports) {
            //Do whatever analysis you need
            Console.WriteLine(r.Date);
            Console.WriteLine(r.Path);
            foreach (var line in r.Lines)
                Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is a "short-n-sweet" version to get down to just the *important* parts:

```
void ProcessReports {
    string[] fileNames = new string[] { "{0:YYYYMMDD}----1234D.dat", "{0:YYYYMMDD}----5678D.dat" };
    DateTime dateStart = new DateTime(year, month, 1); //start of month
    DateTime dateEnd = dateStart.AddMonths(1); //start of NEXT month (i.e. 1 day past end of this month)
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    DateTime date = dateStart;
    while (date < dateEnd) {  //we don't actually get to dateEnd, just the day before it.
        foreach (var fileTemplate in fileNames) {
            //insert the date in YYYYMMDD format
            var file = string.Format(fileTemplate, date);
            if (File.Exists(file)) {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file)) {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        if (true /* insert criteria */)
                            lines.Add(line);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //now jump to next day
        date = date.AddDays(1);
    }   
    //Now we have all the lines. Let's process them;
    foreach (var line in lines) {
        //do something with the report lines
    }
}
```

Comment: @Cylen: Take a look at the way I got the YYYYMMDD formatted dates for each consecutive day in the month. Basically, you just use a `DateTime` object. After each file, you increment the date by calling `AddDays(1)`. Then you can get the date in the "YYYMMDD" format by simply doing `date.ToString("YYYYMMDD")` or analogously, `string.Format("{0:YYYYMMDD}", date);`

Comment: holy schmoly I thought this'd be a 2 line thing. Alas no, but this reads well and makes sense to me, and more importantly doesnt require linq (something i've been told to avoid for now). So if i stick this in above my current code this will replace my current streamreader line?

Comment: The way the code is formatted, you'll have to trim off some of the "boilerplate" code to insert it into your project. For one thing, your code is already part of some namespace, so just copy and paste the code that is within the namespace braces above into your current namespace.

Comment: And you don't really need to copy all of it. Just try to read through and understand what each part is doing. Feel free to ask more questions about anything you don't understand. In the end, you'll probably just want to copy a few lines to get just what you need. The full example I provided was to demonstrate how you can separate your logic into multiple methods to make it easier to understand and maintain each part.

Comment: I added a shortened version that is contained within a single method, just to make it easier for you to see the important parts as far as changing the date in the file name.

Comment: thanks Rico, i've been summoned away from my desk for a while, but will be returning to have a good look through this once i get back properly. Thanks for the help, voted up and accepted :)

Comment: ok Rico, I've had a look at this and while I can figure out how the second part works by reading it, this hasn't translated into me understanding what to do with it regarding my current code. I've updated the original post with what I have at the moment. P.S. Another user recommended I rewrite what I have with using linq, i'm still relatively clueless as to what that does and would prefer not to use it but, beggars cant be choosers.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply move your `foreach` out of your `using` block, then there's nothing stopping you duplicating the `using` block with your second filename, or putting the `using` block inside its own loop that you pass the filenames into:

```
string[] filenames = new string[] {
    "20121203 ----1234D.dat",
    "20121204 ----1234D.dat",
    "20121205 ----1234D.dat" };
List<Whatever> yourListOfMatchingItems = new List<Whatever>();

foreach (string filename in filenames)
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        while (/* whatever you had before */)
        {
            if (/* whatever you had before */)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
foreach (/* item in your list */)
{
}
```

Comment: Hi Rawling, I understand from your reply how to get the other file read by the same program, but I'm unclear as to how I get it to change 20121203 ----1234D.dat to 20121204----1234D.dat (yesterday and today) for example without stopping the program and doing it manually.

Comment: @Cylen I've turned my last example into something more concrete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the name of the file dynamically rather than hard coding it. Then you can loop through all the files to generate your list of values, then process them.

Why not split it up into a few methods? Something like:

```
public void Process()
{
    // logic to get string[] of filenames here. You could loop through each
    // day you need a list for and generate a filename for the given day
    var values = new List<T>();
    foreach (var filename in filenames)
    {
        var valuesFromFile = GetValuesFrom(filename);
        values.AddRange(valuesFromFile);
    }
    ProcessValues(values);
}

private List<T> GetValuesFrom(string filename)
{
    var values = new List<T>();
    while loop //this goes through all the lines in the file. 
    {if //if meets certain criteria then store into a list, otherwise ignore
    }
    return values;
}

private void ProcessValues(List<T> values)
{
    foreach // this part does the analysis of all the values in the list, totals, etc
}
```

T is of course the type of your value